# User profiles from professional social network

Tags: data-request, api, releasing-data, social-media

I'm doing a project in which I need data about users in a professional social network. I need information related to the experience, education, or skills of the users. So far I've tried [LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/) but the API does not allow getting this kind of information and I've also tried [Xing](https://dev.xing.com/docs/resources) but I'm having several problems using the API since the information I retrieve is mostly about test users and not the real ones. I've also searched the web for a dataset with similar characteristics but I couldn't find anything.

Please if you could recommend me another social network with an API that allows developers to retrieve this information or **even better** if you know where can I find a data set with this or similar characteristics I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I've gotten the data by manually calling the Xing API and copying the JSON in to a Java program that saves the wanted atributes into a .csv file. Still waiting for a better way though.

Comment: can you post your comment as an answer, and expand a bit for other people looking to do the same? thanks